# How to handle errors from third party libraries in PHP

Tags: php, error-handling

I've set up my own error handlers which in development stops the application and displays a custom error page with details regardless of the error type (fatal, warnings) etc and this is great because I'm finding all errors easily as they don't end up getting output with HTML.

The problem that I'm having is that sometimes third party libraries throw error warnings which aren't really an issue. This causes the script to stop and display an error which I don't want to see.

For example, I'm using a library that depends on Buzz and it's throwing this error

```
"file_get_contents(): Content-type not specified assuming application/x-www-form-urlencoded".
```

It still works regardless.

Now It's nothing to do with anything I've written I don't want to go in and fix this error myself.

Do you have any ideas as to how I go about handling these types of scenarios?

Comment: Temporarily switch the error handler?

Comment: Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Well, use a different error handler during calls to code that emits these errors. After calling the code, switch back to whatever error handler you want normally.